# Convert time "PT10H30M" to "10:30 AM" time JAVA Android

Tags: java, android, time, timestamp

I'm trying to convert a time in format `"PT10H30M"` to format `"10:30 AM"` and save this on `Date`, time or timestamp variable in Java Android.

Any solution to do this?

Comment: What type of `Object` do you want to end up with? `Calendar`? `Date`?

Comment: I prefer Date or Time, I don´t know if exits Timestamp in JAVA, but any type, just need convert "PT10H30M" to "10:30 AM"

Comment: Your input string represents a span-of-time unattached to the timeline. The correct object representation for that is a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) in java.time (see Answer by Hugo below for [back-port to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)). A time-of-day such as "10:30 AM" is *not* a span-of-time. Your input string is already in the correct textual representation for such a span-of-time, defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, `PT10H30M` is not a time, it's a representing [duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): an **amount** of time (an amount of 10 hours and 30 minutes). That string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Although the **"name"** (10 hours and 30 minutes) is similar to `10:30 AM` (10 hours and 30 minutes AM), they're totally different concepts:

- `10:30 AM` represents a time of the day
- `PT10H30M` represents an amount of time - that can be, for example, added to a date/time:

  - `01:00 AM` plus the duration of `PT10H30M` results in `11:30 AM`
  - `11:00 PM` plus the duration of `PT10H30M` results in `09:30 AM` of the next day

---

Anyway, you could achieve what you want by adding the duration of `PT10H30M` to midnight (`00:00`).

In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. You'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

You can use a [`LocalTime`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalTime.html) (which represents a time, with hour, minutes, seconds and [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)), using a [constant for midnight](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalTime.html#MIDNIGHT) 00:00:00.0, and add a [`Duration`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Duration.html) to it:

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalTime;
import org.threeten.bp.Duration;

LocalTime time = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(Duration.parse("PT10H30M"));
```

The result will be a `time` variable that holds the value corresponding to `10:30 AM`.

---

If you want the corresponding `String`, you can use a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(time.format(fmt));
```

The result is a `String` with the value `10:30 AM`. (Note that I also used a `java.util.Locale` to make sure it properly formats the `String`).

Comment: Exacty what I need, so many, many many thanks to you.

Just a add, for use the
import org.threeten.bp.LocalTime;
import org.threeten.bp.Duration;

Is necesary go to gradle and add dependency

dependencies {    
    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'
}

Comment: @RaZoDiuM On Stack Overflow, you are welcome to make such fixes or additions to an Answer yourself.